# Update a list reference inside a method

Tags: java, list, oop, arraylist, design-patterns

In Java we can not reassign a reference inside a method.
So the following does not work:

```
class SomeClass {  
  List<PaidOrders> paidOrders;  
  List<PendingOrders> pendingOrders;  
  List<CancelledOrders> cancelledOrders;  

  private void process(List<OrderStatus> data, List<Orders> currentOrderlist) {
     List<Order> newOrders = fromOrderStatus(data);  
     currentOrderlist = newOrders;  
  } 
}
```

But the following does work:

```
class SomeClass {  
  
  private void process(List<OrderStatus> data, List<Orders> currentOrderlist) {
     List<Order> newOrders = fromOrderStatus(data);  
     currentOrderlist.clear();  
     currentOrderlist.addAll(newOrders); // <- extra linear loop  
  } 
}
```

The problem is that the second example does an extra linear loop to copy from one list to the other.

Question:
I was wondering, is there some design approach so that I could neatly just replace the references instead? I.e. somehow make the first snippet work with some change in the parameters or something?

**Update**
After the comments I would like to clarify that the `currentOrderList` can be any of the `paidOrders`, `pendingOrders`, `cancelledOrders`.
The code for `process` is the same for all types.

Comment: Is it necessary to pass `currentOrderlist`. You return `newOrders` from method and assign it directly at calling method to `currentOrderlist`

Comment: Have `currentOrderlist` as a field?

Comment: @ScaryWombat: It is already a field, but I have more than one such lists (but with different types stored) as members and they are doing the same processing, so I need to pass the list as a parameter to avoid code duplication. I just simplified the post, perhaps I should add that?

Comment: @VaibS: Please see comment above as well (updated post)

Comment: Maybe adjust `fromOrderStatus` to not work on an entire `List` but return the individual items; then you can do `targetList.clear(); for (Status s : data) targetList.add(fromStatus(s));`. Then you iterate once. Also, how can you add `Person` to all the order lists?

Comment: @daniu: typo, there. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Old school, but if there is only 3 Lists that can be updated, simply pass in the name of the list and update the field - at least it will be easy to understand.

Comment: Why not do it the Java-usual way: return the processed list and have the caller assign it? E.g. `paidOrders = process(data, paidOrders);` ? And are you sure that it's worth worrying about the extra copy step? Did you profile the application, finding this extra step consuming a relevant portion of CPU time?

Comment: Even with the fix, this wouldn't compile with a call like `public void process(data, someClassInstance.paidOrders)`; it would need to be `process(List<Status> data, List<? extends Order> orderList)`. How about a [mcve]? Not to mention that it doesn't make sense for a public method to accept a private List member. Who has access to those?

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I see two possibilities here. Either you use some wrapper object such as AtomicReference (might be a bit overpowered because of the multi-threading issues) as the argument and then just set it there or you use a consumer.

In the second case your method would look like this:

```
public void process(List<OrderStatus> data, Consumer<List<Orders>> target) {
   List<Person> newOrders = fromOrderStatus(data);  
   target.accept(newOrders);  
}
```

Then on the calling side you would implement it like this:

```
process(data, e-> <<targetList>> = e);
```

Comment: In case it helps, the method will never be called by multiple threads. Also I don't really understand the calling code snippet

Comment: In the snippet I'm using a lambda for the expected Consumer-object. With <<targetList>> I want to express, that you have to choose at this place, which of your lists you want to update. So you would for example substitute it with paidOrders. Then after executing it, your paidOrders will be set to the one, given to the consumer.

Comment: What is `<<target>>` list? What is the actual syntax?

Comment: (Sorry - I'm still always pressing enter when I want to make a new line so my answer was at first not very helpful. I edited the actual content)

Answer (score 0):

1. If your list will be wrapped by a different object (for example - `AtomicReference`), then you will be able to change it.

   ```
   public static void doSomething(AtomicReference<List<Integer>> listAtomicReference){
       List<Integer> newIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
       listAtomicReference.set(newIntegers);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       AtomicReference<List<Integer>> listAtomicReference = new AtomicReference<>(Arrays.asList(4));
       doSomething(listAtomicReference);
       System.out.println(listAtomicReference.get());
   }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   []
   ```
2. Making a public member variable in a class.

With that being said, I wouldn't recommend walking this path.

[Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: What exactly is the premature optimization in this approach?

Comment: @Jim "The problem is that the second example does an extra linear loop to copy from one list to the other." Is it really a problem in your use case?

Comment: The point is - the code you wrote is less performant but more readable than the code I wrote above. In most use-cases, we wouldn't even notice any performance differences between the two methods, so I will take what you wrote every given day.